# Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(style:)' for class with Xcode 11 beta 2

Tags: swift

I get the error

> Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(style:)' for class
>
> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

I did not get this error on every previous Xcode I have worked with. I should not get this error, because I am using my own designated initializer. The error can be reproduced by running this git repo: https://github.com/Jasperav/EasyCrash. The relevant code is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false) { (_) in
            let someInitializable: UIViewControllerInitializable.Type = SomeViewController.self

            self.present(someInitializable.init(), animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}

protocol Initializable {
    init()
}

protocol UIViewControllerInitializable: Initializable, UIViewController {}

class BaseTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let a: Int

    init(a: Int) {
        self.a = a

        super.init(style: .plain)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
}

final class SomeViewController: BaseTableViewController, UIViewControllerInitializable {
    init() {
        print("init")

        super.init(a: 10)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

What have been changed with Xcode 11 beta 2? Is this a bug or should I change my code?

[image]

Comment: I copied your code into an Xcode 11 beta 2 Swift playground and I don't see that error. But I did get an error on the `protocol UIViewControllerInitializable: Initializable, UIViewController {}` line due to the redundant constraint of `UIViewController`.

Comment: @rmaddy can you try to run it not inside a playground but a 'real' project? I am not sure if the playground will execute the code exactly the same as a 'real' project.

Comment: @rmaddy I made a small mistake at the Initializable signature, but the problems still remains (but the warning about the redundant constraint is gone)

Comment: @rmaddy When I typed the title of the question inside the box, a lot of similar questions popped up! I will remove the line. If you clone the project and just press run, you don't get the error?

Comment: I've only copied and pasted the code you put into the question. I have not touched your git project.

Comment: @rmaddy Ok, when you create a brand new project in Xcode Beta 2 and you copy paste the code inside ViewController.swift and run it, you should definitely get the error. I cleaned my project, removed the derived data and still get the error.

Comment: Confirmed.  It compiles but crashes at runtime.